# How to convert pytorch model to TensorRT?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, nvidia-jetson, tensorrt

I have trained the classification model on Nvidia GPU and saved the model weights(checkpoint.pth). If I want to deploy this model in jetson nano and test it.

Should I convert it to TenorRT? How to convert it to TensorRT?

I am new to this. It would be helpful if someone can even correct me.

Comment: Do you find a method?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve the way is to export the Onnx model from Pytorch.
Next, use the TensorRT tool, `trtexec`, which is provided by the official Tensorrt package, to convert the TensorRT model from onnx model.

You can refer to this page: https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/blob/master/samples/opensource/trtexec/README.md

The `TRTEXEC` is a more native tool that you can take it from NVIDIA NGC images or downloading from the official website directly.

If you use a tool such as torch2trt, it is easy to encounter the operator issue and complicated to resolve it indeed (if you are not familiar to deal with plugin issues).

Comment: Would you update the web link? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool:

https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/torch2trt

Here are more details how to implent a converter to a engine file:

https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/torch2trt/issues/254

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Torch-TensorRT](https://pytorch.org/TensorRT/).

> Torch-TensorRT is a inference compiler for PyTorch, targeting NVIDIA
> GPUs via NVIDIA’s TensorRT Deep Learning Optimizer and Runtime. It
> supports both just-in-time (JIT) compilation workflows via the
> torch.compile interface as well as ahead-of-time (AOT) workflows.
> Torch-TensorRT integrates seamlessly into the PyTorch ecosystem
> supporting hybrid execution of optimized TensorRT code with standard
> PyTorch code.